# QSortFilterProxyModel and dynamicSortFilter property

Tags: qt, qml

I am using a `QSortFilterProxyModel` and the `dynamicSortFilter` property does not work.

```
// main.cpp
QSortFilterProxyModel carsProxyModel;
carsProxyModel.setSourceModel(&carsModel);
carsProxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(false); // whatever its true or false, it does not change the behavior
```

On the QML side, i have 2 `ListView`, one for the source model and one for the proxy and they display the list of cars in the same way.

When the source model is reversed :

```
// carmodel.cpp
void CarModel::reverseModel()
{
    beginResetModel();
    std::reverse(m_carItems.begin(), m_carItems.end());
    endResetModel();
}
```

Both views shows the reversed list of cars and it is what i expect when the `dynamicSortFilter` is true but not when its false (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#dynamicSortFilter-prop), actually both values always leads to a change in the proxy view.

Maybe i am not using the right property but i cannot see something else so far.

When the source model is reversed - i don't want to see the change in the proxy view, only in the source view. Is this possible ?

Hope this question is clear, i have tried to extract the most important parts because the code base is too long to be posted here.

Thank you.

**EDIT :**

A small example :

if the proxy view is sorted by "car brand" (a `QString`), then reversing the source model will reverse the order of cars with same brand but the sort or filtering is preserved generally (for cars of different brands)

Comment: Did you try to call `sort()` on your proxy model to see if sorting works in general? This might help narrow down the problem. Also, I believe you need to set `dynamicSortfilter` to _true_ if you want your view to sort based no proxy model configuration and ignore the source model's item order. So when the order in the source model changes, it will re-sort it back in the proxy model.

Comment: Yes sorting and filtering works well. Actually - even without sorting and filtering - a change in the source model is always reflected in the proxy view, whatever the value of `dynamicSortFilter` property.

Comment: Just to make clear this is understood; a change in the source model by-default is _always_ reflected in a proxy model.

Answer (score 3):

As @ypnos mentioned, dynamic sorting only affects when the proxy's `sort` is called. If it is `true`, it will be automatically called whenever the source model changes. It does not affect how the objects are sorted; this is up to your implementation

However, I read in you question that you have 2 views on 1 list, that need to be sorted differently. I suggest you use 2 distinct `QProxyFilterModels`, one for each view, and don't handle sorting in the base model at all.

The "reverse" model could simply invert the order of the original list by mapping the items in reverse order:

```
QModelIndex ReverseProxyModel::mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &sourceIndex) const {
    if (reversed) {
        return createIndex(sourceModel()->rowCount() - sourceIndex.row(), sourceIndex.column());
    } else {
        return createIndex(sourceModel()->rowCount(), sourceIndex.column());
    }
}

// Similar for mapToSource
```

Comment: A very fine suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

So the issue at hands here is that you would like to control the total order of elements, not just how they are ordered according to DisplayRole. You need to make the proxy model aware of your total order which includes multiple attributes of the items.

As is explained [in the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#sorting):

> Custom sorting behavior is achieved by subclassing QSortFilterProxyModel and reimplementing lessThan(), which is used to compare items.

The dynamic sorting property is not doing what you believe it is doing. Actually it is a trigger to `sort()` on the proxy model whenever the source model changes. But the default sorter for QStrings will not change the order of items that look the same to it (it is a so-called *stable sorter*). Even if it were not a stable sorter, you would get basically random shuffling of the items at best after each source model change.

Note that you cannot prevent changes in the source order to be propagated through the proxy directly; you need to suppress them by providing a sorter that completely controls the order. So `lessThan()` would take into consideration car brand, make, color, etc. Alternatively, you could store the initial index of each item and use that as a secondary key in sorting after the brand. So basically:

```
if (a.brand == b.brand)
    return a.index < b.index;
return a.brand < b.brand;
```

Comment: Ok what i understand is that the default sorting algorithm is stable regarding the source model, not the proxy one and is applied after a source model change so if the model is reversed first, then it will preserve it and that's what i get. But if  `dynamicSortFilter` is false, i would expect the proxy view is not sorted nor filtered after a source model change but it is.

Comment: Again, any change in the source model is propagated through the proxy, and `dynamicSortFilter` has no influence on this. Really, your idea of `dynamicSortFilter` is **wrong**. A proxy does not take a snapshot of the source model, it always operates on live data, and if the source changes the proxy changes with it. As explained in my answer, you can tighten the sorting to bury the order changes in the source.

Comment: Thanks. And how would you retrieve the initial `QModelIndex` list in the proxy model as suggested ?

Comment: I would not use a model index here, just an ascending number that I set while inserting the items into the model. I don't know which kind of items you have in your model, but in general, you can store it in the item's data as Qt::UserRole+1, for example with model->setItemData(). That way it's pretty trivial to obtain, because in lessThan() you can fetch itemData() and use, e.g., both Qt::DisplayRole and Qt::UserRole+1 in the comparisons.